# Notes in PDF with xslt

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, apache-fop

I'm trying to get comments/notes to my output PDF file with the Apache Formatting Object Processor. Could't find anything about it.

What I have tried is to highlight the text and simply write the note underneath it. But that would completely distort the look of the rendered PDF.

In XML i have something like.

```
<paragraph>
   <text>Hello World!<text>
   <note>Note for "Hello World!" text</note>
</paragragh>
```

What I would like to have is a note associated with the text, as it is possible with the comment function of other PDF editors like Adobe Acrobat or Foxit.

Is that possible with Apache FOP and XSLT?

Comment: I looked through the documentation and see no FOP extension for PDF comments. I do know that RenderX supports "rx:pdf-comment" as an extension to create note-like PDF comments and I suspect Antennahouse has a similar extension. But I could not find the equivalent in FOP and you cannot just create something like that without writing your own extension for FOP.